# rpmbuild - /usr/sbin Symlink not installing

Tags: symlink, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm setting up a Redis RPM for a local, unnetworked box. I'm trying to create a symlink:  /usr/sbin/redis-server -> /opt/redis/redis-server

However, when I do an `rpm -Uvh redis-3.2.7-1.rpm`, it installed fine to `/opt/redis/redis-server` but never creates the symlink.  Here's the relevant part of my spec file:

```
%build
# Empty section.

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
rm -f /usr/sbin/redis-server

mkdir -p  %{buildroot}

# in builddir
cp -a * %{buildroot}

ln -sf /opt/redis/redis-server /usr/sbin/redis-server

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
/opt/redis/*
/etc/init.d/redis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ln -sf /opt/redis/redis-server /usr/sbin/redis-server` needs to be `ln -sf /opt/redis/redis-server %{buildroot}/usr/sbin/redis-server` and then `/usr/sbin/redis-server` needs to be added to the `%files` section. Also remove that `rm` in `%install`.

The fact that the `ln` did *not* fail tells me you really made the symlink, and you're building RPMs as root which is a spectacularly bad idea.

I'm assuming that the tarball expands with `opt` at the top level; if not your `cp` is incorrect as well.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. My issue was I wasn't creating the `usr/sbin` directory in my tarball.

Comment: And I'm only running as root because I'm doing it in a Docker container. So no worries on that.

Comment: You could do the `mkdir -p` from the specfile too if you want.